# Why I am unable to detect nystose & kestose using hplc and refractive index detector while could see peaks of glucose,sucrose,fructose, and raffinose

Tags: chromatography

Mobile phase is 60% acetonitrile and temperature of the column is 25 degrees (supercosil amino from sigma). RID is also set up at 25.

Comment: For readers, see [www.researchgate.net  - Structures-of-inulin-type-fructan-1-kestose-A-nystoseB-and-inulinC](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Structures-of-inulin-type-fructan-1-kestose-A-nystoseB-and-inulinC_fig1_50998843)

Comment: You might also consider trying a resin that is more suitable for oligosaccharides. Shodex, for example, sells a number of different saccharides analysis columns. Here is a comparison of their fructooligosaccharide column to an amino column showing the peaks for nystose and kestose: https://www.shodex.com/en/dc/03/03/46.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The same column and the mobile phase concentration was used by one of our scientists in lab with the same column. They quantified the same sugars.So I thought of moving forward with the same. It's bit strange that they are not working for me.

Comment: I haven't tried 95% water. That's a good idea. Although I used 75% acn and the results were same.

Comment: @Andrew, Gradient cannot be used with RI detector.

Comment: Please include additional information into your post.

Comment: @AChem - I do have personal experience running RI detectors for carbohydrate analysis for about ten years in my lab, but I only have changed the solvent composition once or twice out of desperation, and looking back, it's likely that we used the inline UV detector in those cases rather than the RI. I'll remove that comment. But I still believe that OP's likely problem is that the oligosaccharides are being retained on the column for longer than the run under the given conditions.

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. Is there any chance that the brand new column could be faulty? People in my lab used to do sugar analysis like in 2016. So, I got a new column for myself. Since then I have been running  exactly the same protocol. The old protocol run time was 12 min and I have been running for 25 minutes and still no luck. So, just assuming maybe the manufacturers have made some change in their resin.

Comment: I will definitely try more water in my mobile phase composition and increase my run time specifically for those oligosaccharides.

Answer (score 1):

Bonding alkyl amino groups on silica is just like an auto-immune disease. The basic amine groups help to dissolve very silica substrate in aqueous mobile phases. Amino-silica columns are typically not very stable (hydrolytically). This is why many amino-phases have a polymeric substrate. When an HPLC column misbehaves, it is time run the quality control (QC) test sheet that comes with the column. Make sure the column is within its specs. Since one cannot run a gradient with a refractive index detector, it is possible to use relatively deep UV on an ordinary HPLC UV detector and a gradient method, with wavelengths around 210 nm etc. Many older methods that analysed sugars used this trick. The UV cut off of ACN is 190 nm. It is likely your sugar has a high retention time under your HPLC methods. In the so-called hydrophilic interaction liquid chromatography (HILIC) mode, analytes follow a U-shaped curve with respect to retention factor and ACN percentage.